# How to securely connect two VPC without using Connection Peering

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Suppose some services are running on EC2 instances on `VPC A` and other services are running on on-premise hardware or even other Cloud Computing environments, say `Cluster B` equipped with the public IP. We want to securely connect the `VPC A` instances to `cluster B` instances (two-way), as the services need to be in connection with each other. As an attempt, I created a Client VPN Endpoint and associate it with the VPC A but the problem is it seems such a VPN is one-way and the VPC A instances can not route to the nodes connected to the VPN. So what is the best solution for connecting `VPC A` to 'Cluster B' using a secure connection?

Comment: Why you don’t want to use VPC Peering? It’s the natural answer to your question. If you’ve got specific reasons or requirements that prevent you from using VPC peering they may be relevant to any other solution too. Better explain those first.

Comment: @MLu Good point. The problem with VPC Peering is that it limits us to the AWS environment. In our case, the services running on VPC are always AWS instances but the services running on VPC B can be deployed on even on-promise hardware or other Cloud Computing environments. I've updated the question with this information.